# How to find a simple expression for these matrix transforms?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X = (X_{i,j})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ be a $n\times n $ matrix.

Let $A$ be a $n\times n $ matrix.

Let $(e^1, \ldots, e^n)$ be the canonical matrix of $\mathbb R^n$.

Is there a simple way to write the following sums:

1. the vector $\sum_{1 \le  i, j \le n} X_{i,j} (e^i-e^j)$;
2. the matrix $\sum_{1 \le  i,j \le n} X_{i,j} (e^i-e^j)(e^i-e^j)'$;
3. the vector $\sum_{1 \le  i,j \le n} X_{i,j} (e^i-e^j)(e^i-e^j)'A(e^i-e^j)$?

Remark: Here $'$ means transpose

Comment: For 1) I have $(X-X') 1$ where $1$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ with all coordinates equal to 1.